# Error duplicate key on INSERT with SELECT NOT EXISTS

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

How could happen this?

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "r_u_pkey"  
DETAIL:  Key (r_id, u_id)=(2660, 10182) already exists.  
 'INSERT INTO r_u(r_id, u_id) SELECT %s, %s WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM r_u WHERE r_id = %s AND u_id = %s
 )' (2660, 10182, 2660, 10182)
```

There is primary key on `(r_id, u_id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE r_u  
(  
  r_id integer NOT NULL,  
  u_id integer NOT NULL,  
  CONSTRAINT r_u_pkey PRIMARY KEY (r_id, u_id)  
)
```

Server is Postgres 9.3.5 and connection has autocommit on.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5ccfd/5  - example @ SqlFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found reason and solution. INSERT SELECT is not atomic. In autocommit mode must be used explicit locking in transaction:

`BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE r_u IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO r_u(r_id, u_id) SELECT %s, %s WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM r_u WHERE r_id = %s AND u_id = %s
 )
COMMIT;`

Source:http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/upsert/